# Converting WKT to GeoJSON with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, convert, php, well-known-text

I have a point-type WKT geometry column in a MySQL table storing the location of some stores.

I want to display it on a Leaflet map on my website. I've found plenty of tutorials for doing this on Leaflet's official website from GeoJSON data.

However, I found no precise documentation which clearly explains how to convert WKT to GeoJSON...even if it seems to be a very important part of the process.

Does someone know a good source which fills this gap or can explain to me how to do this in PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 10):

If you've already got WKT, then you might considering using the JavaScript library, [Wicket](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/), to go straight from your WKT to Leaflet features. As this example shows, you can pass in a WKT string and a style/options object, and Wicket will return a feature object you can attach directly to a Leaflet FeatureGroup, etc.

This example assumes two things: 1) You have an existing layer or [`featureGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) already and instantiated and added to your map, and 2) you have an existing icon style for your markers. In this case I just assumed [the `greenIcon` marker style from the official Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html).

```
var wkt_geom = "POINT(34.0218531, -81.0707438)";
var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
wicket.read(wkt_geom);

// "greenIcon from official documentation noted above.
var feature = wicket.toObject({icon: greenIcon});

// Presumably featureGroup is already instantiated and added to your map.
featureGroup.addLayer(feature);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Wicket, there is also [Wellknown](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown)

```
// With Leaflet or MapBox.js
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(parse('Point(1 2)'));
```

Comment: This method seems to be easier, but needs node.js. Is it necessary to dive into node.js to run it ? I'm a beginner programmer and don't know if it's a good idea to go in node.js while being still learning javascript...

Comment: This is intriguing, but I dislike the additional dependencies.

Comment: @elrobis, there are no dependencies and you don't need Node (unless you want to run on the command line). For use in browser, you just include this: https://raw.github.com/mapbox/wellknown/master/wellknown.js

Comment: @toms are you certain? The usage notes state _and in browsers via [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) or a standalone package_. I confess that I'm not sure what that means. So you're saying `wellknown.js` can be used as-is, without any additional libs or `require()` calls?

Comment: @elrobis I was wrong. I took the documentation at face value and assumed that "stand alone" meant that wellknown.js would ... stand alone. But just tested and it does not. So you are correct, it requires node or packaging using something like browserify.   Apologies for the giving bad advice

Comment: NP just wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding something :)

Answer (score 2):

As of leaflet 1.5, wicket's `.toObject()` method isn't working out for me. It created a feature and got mapped, but I could not get any `onEachFeature` type action to work with it. But the `.toJson()` function converts to the geometry component of a standard geojson feature, and I took that forward.

```
var wkt_geom = "POINT(34.0218531, -81.0707438)";
var wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
wkt.read(wkt_geom);
var feature = { "type": "Feature", 'properties': {}, "geometry": wkt.toJson() };
```

Now "feature" is a simple json with proper geojson syntax (and no functions, objects etc in it; just data!), and it can be loaded into leaflet/map using `L.geoJson(feature)`. If you want metadata to go with your shape, you can assign it by:

```
feature.properties = { ... };
```

and after that do the `L.geoJson(feature)` declaration.

I've had a similar experience with turfJS : get the data down to the native json structure and then proceed, rather than trying to shove one library's object into another's. A few years on they usually diverge.

Comment: same problem here but with leaflet 1.7. wicket's toObject() not working. Your contribution solvd my problem. thanks

Comment: aw shucks. will update here if I find a way forward for v1.7+

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the wicket GitHub, I found that `toJson()` gives an object, as shown in their example code:

```
// Convert to GeoJSON
wkt.toJson(); // Outputs an object
JSON.stringify(wkt.toJson());
// Outputs a string
```